# What are all the IP Address to white list to receive the incoming messages from the wechat server

Tags: wechat, wechat-official-account

What are all the IP Address to white list to receive the incoming messages from the wechat server.

There is a webhook URL we have to be configured in wechat console mp.wexin.qq.com to receive the incoming messages.

The following ips addres we have identified for whitelisting to receive the messages, not sure these may change .

i would like to know the list of ip address for wechat server. Can any one have this information  or please provide some lead from where i can get this information.

```
machine@1:~/Work/cryptographic-workspace/keystore-cryptographic-service$ nslookup mp.weixin.qq.com
Server:     172.17.5.36
Address:    172.17.5.36#53

Non-authoritative answer:
mp.weixin.qq.com    canonical name = mpv6.weixin.qq.com.
Name:   mpv6.weixin.qq.com
Address: 203.205.239.172
Name:   mpv6.weixin.qq.com
Address: 203.205.239.154
Name:   mpv6.weixin.qq.com
Address: 203.205.239.171

machine@2:~/Work/cryptographic-workspace/keystore-cryptographic-service$ nslookup api.weixin.qq.com
Server:     172.17.5.36
Address:    172.17.5.36#53

Non-authoritative answer:
api.weixin.qq.com   canonical name = hk.api.weixin.qq.com.
Name:   hk.api.weixin.qq.com
Address: 203.205.239.82
Name:   hk.api.weixin.qq.com
Address: 203.205.239.94
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the following documentation

https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/en/Basic_Information/Get_the_WeChat_server_IP_address.html

They provide an API to query the list of possible callback server ips.